# Make selected mat-option as active with checkmark

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-autocomplete, mat-option

I am using mat-autocomplete, from the dropdown when manually one of the option is selected, the selected item is indicated with different bg color and a checkmark on right side.

But when one of the dropdown item is pragmatically set, the item is not highlighted.
I use setValue() to programmatically to set the value.

Comment: It will be easier for others to help if you can create a stackblitz of the same

Answer (score 0):

1- Add a new property to your data model like:

```
options: {key:string,isSelected:boolean}[] = [{key:'One',isSelected:false},{key:'Two',isSelected:false},{key:'Three',isSelected:false}];
```

2- Add the `[displayWith]` property to `mat-autocomplete` to work with the function that helps us to set/get value to mat-option

```
<mat-autocomplete requireSelection #auto="matAutocomplete"  [displayWith]="displaySelectedData()">
```

3- Use a function to bind data to mat autocomplete

```
displaySelectedData = () => (value: string): string =>{return !value ? this.fetchedData :  value}
```

fetchedData is the default value e.g. `this.fetchedData = "Four"`

4- Add ngClass to mat-option

```
<mat-option  [ngClass]="{'myClass': option.isSelected}"
```

then

```
.myClass {background-color: var(--mat-option-selected-state-layer-color)}
```

5- Now the option that already had data has a new style. finally if want to add a checkbox to your option just use the material checkbox in the mat-option tag.

6- Finally you should change `options` object `isSelected` value to `true | false` to manage ngClass changes. use `(optionSelected)='method($event)'` on `mat-autocomplete` to change   `options` object property value.